# Построчная обработка файла

Tags: c#

Необходимо построчно обработать файл. Основная проблема заключается в том, что нужна вся строка **целиком**, то есть символы переноса строки, каретки должны остаться. Но в тоже время предполагается, что файлы могут быть очень большими, из-за чего может не хватить памяти. Как это оптимально можно реализовать?

([StreamReaderObj].ReadLine() - возвращает строку не полностью (без символов конца строки), File.ReadAllText and etc. - память)

**upd:** Мне важно знать какой у конкретной строки перенос(\r\n or \n)

Comment: символ переноса строки отделяет одну строку от другой. вы хотите, чтобы некоторые такие символы не учитывались при разбиении?

Comment: @СергейКоновалов если есть строка "some text\n", то [StreamReaderObj].ReadLine() - вернет "some text", а мне нужна вся строка. Т.к. конец строки может отличаться.

Comment: А кодировка файла у вас какая? Или нужно все поддерживать с преамбулами?

Comment: @Zergatul utf-8

Comment: Используйте `BinaryReader`, как уже предложили в ответе, и разбирайте данные вручную. С учетом того, что файлы могут быть большими, нужно читать большими блоками, методом `ReadChars`. Разница в скорости может отличаться на порядок. См. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542374/184217).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел код в интернете который расширяет бинари ридер и немного его изменил под нужды автора вопроса:

```
public static class BinaryReaderExtension
{
    public static String ReadLine(this BinaryReader reader)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        bool foundEndOfLine = false;
        char ch;

        while (!foundEndOfLine)
        {
            try
            {
                ch = reader.ReadChar();
            }
            catch (EndOfStreamException ex)
            {
                if (result.Length == 0) return null;
                else break;
            }

            result.Append(ch);

            switch (ch)
            {
                case '\r':
                    if (reader.PeekChar() == '\n') reader.ReadChar();
                    foundEndOfLine = true;
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    foundEndOfLine = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Изменения я не тестировал,**  так что может что-то пойти не так...)

Но, возможно, код и полностью рабочий.

Comment: Насколько я понял автору важны символы конца строки, потому что они могут быть разные. `StreamReader` рубит строки по 3 возможным вариантам: `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`.

Comment: Мне важно знать какой у конкретной строки перенос(\r\n or \n). Он может отличаться от Environment.NewLine, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Здесь все пойдет не так, в UTF-8 символ может быть 2-байтный, и один из байтов может быть `\r` или `\n` и это не будет конец строки :)

Comment: @Artyom - _Мне важно знать какой у конкретной строки перенос(\r\n or \n)_ - почему этого нет в самом вопросе?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавил

Comment: @Zergatul но в BinaryReader можно передать кодировку. Должен все правильно читать, нет?

Comment: @Artyom да, вы правы, должно сработать